# Freeze method runs into File Exists Error in Frozen Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Does anyone know how to use frozen flask??? I need help with making a website and hosting it on github. I don't have a problem hosting it on github, but I have a problem with the actual freeze() process. It works for a little bit, but then I run into a FileExistsError. But I don't have any files that have the same name. The views.py routes are set up so general that it takes state/state-abbreviation/other.

```
from flask_frozen import Freezer
from flask import Flask
from website import app

freezer = Freezer(app)
app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py') #use this to not delete files after freezing, and move all static files into project directory for GH to see.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freezer.freeze()
    # app.run(debug=True)
```

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, url_for

@core.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", states=states_array, other=Other_Resources)


@core.route('/state/<state_code>')
def state(state_code=None):
    if state is None:
        raise ValueError('No state given')
    title = states_dict[state_code]
    return render_template('state_home_page.html', title=title, states=states_array, code=state_code, other=Other_Resources)


@core.route('/state/<state_code>/donate')
def state_donate(state_code=None):
    title = states_dict[state_code]
    try:
        data = state_to_category['Donate'][state_code]
    except KeyError:
        data = []
    return render_template('state_donate.html', title=title, states=states_array, data=data, code=state_code, other=Other_Resources)

@core.route('/state/<state_code>/organizations')
def state_org(state_code=None):
    title = states_dict[state_code]
    try:
        data = state_to_category['Organization'][state_code]
    except KeyError:
        data = []
    return render_template('state_org.html', title=title, states=states_array, data=data, code=state_code, other=Other_Resources)

@core.route('/state/<state_code>/blackbusiness')
def state_biz(state_code=None):
    title = states_dict[state_code]
    try:
        data = state_to_category['Business'][state_code]
    except KeyError:
        data = []
    return render_template('state_biz.html', title=title, states=states_array, data=data, code=state_code, other=Other_Resources)

@core.route('/State_list')
def State_list():
    return render_template("state_list.html", states=states_array, other=Other_Resources)

@error_pages.app_errorhandler(404)
def error_404(error):
    return render_template('error_pages/404.html', states=states_array), 404
```

And I think it messes up after freezing state/ca/, then trying to freeze state/ca/donate and on.

this is my repo https://github.com/mrodriguez3313/Support-bipoc Please check it out so you can fork and try for yourself please. I have a branch where I did my testing, called MAR-freezingapp. You can see what I did attempted to do. Frozen Flask documentation sounds like things should "just work", when you run the .freeze() method, it will create static files in a build/ folder for you. But when I run `python app.py`

these are the errors I get

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'NationalOrganizations' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'NationalPetitions' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'NationalDonate' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'State_list' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'ca' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'mn' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'tx' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'ga' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'la' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py:199: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'donate' (type application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    freezer.freeze()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 199, in freeze
    return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 199, in <genexpr>
    return set(page.url for page in self.freeze_yield())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 183, in freeze_yield
    new_filename = self._build_one(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 344, in _build_one
    os.makedirs(dirname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/c/Users/marco/Documents/Udemy/WebDev/SiteProject/state/ca'
```

I tried seeing if I could wrap .freeze() in a try/except, but it still comes to a halt. Maybe I'm not doing it right? I tried running freeze.run(debug=True), but it also just breaks with same errors. I can still run the app using `flask run`. Thank you in advanced for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned your project and was able to successfully freeze and serve it (using browser-sync) after adding trailing slashes to the routes in `core/views.py`. I was having a similar issue with my project and adding trailing slashes to my routes solved the issue. More related discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/335cyi/a_problem_with_frozenflask/

Also Frozen Flask doesn't guarantee that it "just works" in every case. E.g. in the documentation, they mention the need to write url generators in some cases. ( https://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#url-generators ), though this doesn't appear to be relevant for your app.

Comment: Thank you for the response! And thank you for pointing me to that reddit topic. I was on there as well and I couldn't find a similar topic/discussion. I saw the topic on URL Generators as well and didn't think it fit my use case.